# distribution of diagonal entries of Hermite Normal Forms

Tags: random-matrices, lattices

Consider a $n$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ over the integers and let $H$ be its Hermite Normal Form. Is there any result about the distribution of the diagonal entries of $H$, when $A$ is "randomly selected"? For example, each entry of $A$ can be uniformly random from some $[0, N)$?

Answer (score 3):

This problem was studied by Gerard Maze in [Natural Density Distribution of Hermite Normal Forms of Integer Matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.4826) (2010). One result:

The probability that an $n\times n$ integer matrix $A$ has an Hermite normal form (HNF) with the integers $d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_{n−1},d$ on the diagonal is given by
$$\bigl(\zeta(n)\zeta(n-1)\cdots\zeta(2)d_1^n d_2^{n-1}\cdots d_{n-1}^2\bigr)^{-1},$$
with $\zeta(n)$ the Riemann zeta function.

The expectation value and variance of a diagonal element have been calculated by Hu et al. in [On random nonsingular Hermite Normal Form](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X16000354) (2015, paywall). I quote their result:

[image]

Note that the distribution of the matrices is different in the two papers: Maze chooses the matrix elements uniformly in the interval $(-M,M)$ for large $M$, while Hu et al. choose the determinant uniformly from that interval.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A follow up question: has anyone studied the conditional distribution of the diagonal terms in the Smith normal form, given the diagonals on the Hermite normal form?

Comment: you may want to ask this second question in a separate thread, it seems largely unrelated to your first question.